# Google App Engine dev_appserver can't find PIL (I've installed it)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I recently upgraded my Google App Engine launcher on my Mac, running OSX 10.5.8, and afterwards my projects that work with images stopped working locally.

It seems to be the same problem that I had when first using GAE locally to work with images, before I installed PIL.  Here is the error I get:

```
SystemError: Parent module 'PIL' not loaded
```

I have PIL installed.  When I run python normally, I can access it and work with it as expected.  I also checked to ensure that dev_appserver.py was running the same version of Python.  If I open the interpreter and type sys.version I get this back:

```
2.5 (r25:51918, Sep 19 2006, 08:49:13)
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 5341)]
```

This is identical to what I get when I display the sys.version from my projects running through dev_appserver.  Any thoughts on why dev_appserver can't find the PIL module?  I have been banging my head against this for a bit.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be suffering from the problems I was explaining [here](http://aleaxit.blogspot.com/2008/09/pil-on-mac-os-x-105-with-google-app.html), specifically, I think...:

> You need to find another way to extend Python `sys.path`'s
>   appropriately. The simplest way is to
>   make a file named `PIL.pth` with a
>   single-line content:
>
> `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages`
>
> and place that PIL.pth in any of the
>   directories that all Python processes
>   see; in my case, I used
>   `/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/` --
>   but that directory is not available in
>   a pristine installation of Mac OS X
>   10.5 so you may have to use some other directory.

Comment: You are my hero; thanks so much, that did the trick.  Never would have come up with that on my own.  If anyone else reads this post, I put my PIL.pth file in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/, as Alex mentions the path he referenced did not exist on my machine

Comment: Is there a way to do this with other modules that are temperamental? I'm having trouble with a `__future__` import, but making a similar file named `__future__.pth` or `future.pth` does not seem to work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853710