# Virtualenv __future__ module works on command line, but not while running dev_appserver.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine, virtualenv, importerror

I'm running into a strange error when running App Engine from within my **virtualenv**. Here is the error:

```
File "/home/matthew/dev/sdks/google_appengine_1.5.2/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2318, in LoadModuleRestricted description)
File "/home/matthew/dev/projects/webapp2/project/src/webapp2.py", line 11, in <module>
  from __future__ import with_statement
ImportError: No module named __future__
```

- If I run python in my virtualenv and type `import __future__`, it
  imports.
- If I deactivate my virtualenv and run **dev_appserver.py**, the
  app works.
- But if my virtualenv is active AND I run dev_appserver.py (even
  though #1 is true), the app does not work and I get the error above.

Why would `__future__` be available while running the Python interpreter, but not dev_appserver.py?

Comment: Does `dev_appserver.py` work if you remove the future statement? Can it find other imports in the virtualenv? It could just seem like `__future__` is the problem because it's the first line of the file.

Comment: Yes, but it runs into another error later because it does not understand the "with" syntax without it.

Comment: `from __future__ import` and `import __future__` aren't actually the same... the first is a future statement, not really an import, and is treated specially by the bytecompiler. The second actually imports the real module `__future__`. Does the first work in the interpreter in the virtualenv?

Comment: Also, `dev_appserver.py` uses pretty complicated semantics to import modules, using the `imp` module and PEP 302 import hooks. It seems to me this could mess up future statements or module imports in odd situations pretty easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [bug 4339](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4339). Make sure you use the SDK version 1.6.0, then do:

```
$ cd /usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools
$ wget "http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=43390029000&name=dev_appserver_import_hook.patch&token=974d9f138a5604dc7eb0526156b26cc7" -O dev_appserver.patch
$ patch -p1 < dev_appserver.patch
```